# Managing conflicting dependencies in Gemfile.lock

Tags: ruby, ssh, rubygems, net-ssh, gemfile.lock

In my gemspec file:

- I have a gem dependency called zconfig that explicitly requires net-ssh version 2.6.8
- I'm also using net-sftp, which in turn requires net-ssh version >= 2.6.5

When I `bundle install`, bundler is smart enough to recognize the needs of both gems and correctly identifies 2.6.8 as the version of net-ssh to install.

```
net-sftp (2.1.2)
  net-ssh (>= 2.6.5)
...
net-ssh (2.6.8)
...
zconfig (0.2.7)
  mysql (~> 2.9.1)
  mysql2 (~> 0.3.13)
  net-ssh (~> 2.6.8)
  net-ssh-gateway (~> 1.2.0)
  sequel (~> 4.1.0)
  sqlite3 (~> 1.3.7)
```

So far, while testing on the remote server, I've been cloning the project and installing these gems with `bundle install --deployment` and then running the project with the locally instaled vendor gems using `bundle exec ..`

However, I'm now done with development and I've packaged the project as a gem and installed it on the remote server. The problem is that when executing the gem ruby doesn't adhere to my Gemfile.lock specification and uses net-ssh 2.7.0, which causes a conflict:

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:1615:in `raise_if_conflicts': Unable to activate zconfig-0.2.7, because net-ssh-2.7.0 conflicts with net-ssh (~> 2.6.8) (Gem::LoadError)
```

Is there a way to do something like `bundle exec my_gem` so that it uses the Gemfile.lock specifications?

Comment: It certainly is possible to start the remote server with `bundle exec`. How is the remote server started now?

Another option may be to remove the 2.7.0 version of the gem from the server. (Assuming that no one else on that server needs it....)

Comment: if you are packaging your project as a gem, you need to specify the dependencies in your `project.gemspec`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define the specific version of the gem to a required version by adding the following line in the [gemfile](/questions/tagged/gemfile):

```
gem 'net-ssh', '2.6.8'
```

or in the **thinegem.gemspec**:

```
spec.add_dependency 'net-ssh', '2.6.8'
```

And if you did add the [gemfile.lock](/questions/tagged/gemfile.lock) into the project, it shell be used during a deployment anyway.